# GridBagConstraints Not Correctly Aligning JRadioButton Box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jradiobutton

GridBagConstraints aren't working even with .weightx, .weighty, and .anchor specified. 
I need the component to be set in the top left but it keeps being set in the center of the screen. Below is the method I have for positioning the component.

```
private void initGUI(){
    getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));

    Box buttonBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
    ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();

    buttons.add(okOnly);
    buttons.add(okCancel);
    buttons.add(yesNoCancel);
    buttons.add(yesNo);

    buttonBox.add(okOnly);
    buttonBox.add(okCancel);
    buttonBox.add(yesNoCancel);
    buttonBox.add(yesNo);
    buttonBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Buttons"));

    GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
    gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gridConstraints.weightx = 1;
    gridConstraints.weighty = 1;

    panel.add(buttonBox, gridConstraints);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

Comment: Been a while since I used GridBag stuff, so this may be a stupid comment, but: Your GridBagLayout is on the content pane but your pass the constraints when you add the buttonBox to a different panel. Are you sure all that is right?

Comment: @John3136: no, it's not alright. See code below.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was there was no layout manager for the panel, which i was adding too. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're giving the GridBagLayout to the contentPane, but adding a component to it without GridBagConstraints, and then giving **no** layout to your panel JPanel, so that it uses the default FlowLayout, and adding components to it using GridBagConstraints, constraints that have no meaning in this situation.

Solution: obviously don't do this. Only use GridBagConstraints when adding components to a container that uses GridBagLayout.

In fact, I'd simply get rid of the panel JPanel if all you need is a collection of JRadioButtons in the upper left corner:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
    private JRadioButton okOnly = new JRadioButton("Ok ");
    private JRadioButton okCancel = new JRadioButton("Ok Cancel");
    private JRadioButton yesNoCancel = new JRadioButton("Yes No Cancel");
    private JRadioButton yesNo = new JRadioButton("Yes No");

    private void initGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        // JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));

        Box buttonBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        ButtonGroup buttons = new ButtonGroup();

        buttons.add(okOnly);
        buttons.add(okCancel);
        buttons.add(yesNoCancel);
        buttons.add(yesNo);

        buttonBox.add(okOnly);
        buttonBox.add(okCancel);
        buttonBox.add(yesNoCancel);
        buttonBox.add(yesNo);
        buttonBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Buttons"));

        GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridConstraints.weightx = 1;
        gridConstraints.weighty = 1;

        // panel.add(buttonBox, gridConstraints);
        add(buttonBox, gridConstraints);
        // getContentPane().add(panel);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        new Gui().initGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```